# Boss vs StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

If your boss sees that you spend a lot of time on StackOverflow to solve other's problems, how can you explain it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My code is compiling.

[image: Are you stealing those LCDs?' 'Yeah, but I'm doing it while my code compiles.]

If seriously, tell him that:

- Attempting to answer a question or to teach something to somebody is the best way to get a deeper understanding of the problem for yourself
- By regularly and intentionally getting involved in a vast variety of programming problems you expand your knowledge horizons and stay up-to-date, which makes you a better professional than that COBOL dinosaur at the desk in the corner, from which your boss only benefits.

Comment: I cannot increase your reputation because I don't have too much points, but your answer is really funny. Thank you!

Comment: :-(  Too bad we develop in interpreted languages...

Comment: @Maurizio, if you have 200 points on SO (which it seems you do), you can associate your accounts to get a 100-point bonus.

Comment: @mmyers, how can I do that?

Comment: @Pavel then the excuse is "it's running the test suite" -- ahh, you have that, don't you? Otherwise SO is a great way to learn about that.

Comment: @Maurizio: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144873?tab=accounts#tab-top

Answer (score 21):

Send him the link to [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/).

He'll be spending days there answering business-related questions of other people.

Comment: +1 Hahahahahahaha! Instead of getting back to work, infecting the boss as well. Great idea. :)

Comment: Another nice answer!!! I didn't know that site.

Answer (score 11):

If you spend *a lot* of time solving other people's problems, maybe you can't explain why. You are paid to solve *certain* problems of interest to your employer, not any arbitrary software problem that may be happening at some point of the planet.

Comment: +1 participating in SO is a great thing, but doing so on someone else's time? I don't know. If I had employees, I would allow *some*
 participation, but with *very* strict limitations - knowing how easy it is to spend a lot of time here....

Comment: @Pekka: I agree. That's what I do actually (as an employee). Small lapses of disconnect-and-answer-something are ok and do good to your brain, but dedicating "a lot" of time to these things would be just slacking off.

Answer (score 6):

I tell him it's an investment in a community/service that's provided me with dozens of good answers to hard problems.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe explaining it is the wrong thing to do. What is it you get paid to do again?

Answer (score 5):

I'd explain and show to him a question I posted about that particular problem no one else could solve in the project for the last two weeks and how fast it was solved by using StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

My boss says that it's cool that I'm on Stackoverflow, sharing my knowledge and learning from others.  That makes me a better programmer, which benefits the team.

Of course, I should stop my working hours tracker when I enter SO.  But my boss nevertheless says it's cool... And I start suspecting that...

Answer (score 2):

"Stackoverflow is a programming questions and answers site.  I use it to expose myself to new technologies, to hone my skills, and to find answers to pressing questions and roadblocks."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if it's a problem then your boss *should* be putting pressure on you.

Or if it's not a problem but your boss thinks it is and your boss wouldn't understand then maybe you should find a new boss (aka new job).